# Spreadsheets, function for getting the currency unit of a cell

Tags: spreadsheet

Not really an SO question but I don't want to play "guess the password" with Yahoo Answers, and there's no other place.

I have some cells in a column called "cost" and they are entered in a few different currencies, I'd like to have a column where the values in the "cost" columns are represented in my local currency.

It'd be easy enough if I could use if statements, `if(???=="$",cell*$[cell with conversion rate],[nested if statements])` but I'm not sure what the ??? is, I've been searching but without knowing what I'm looking for it has been fruitless.

Comment: There's [su], which is specifically for non-programming related software and computer questions.

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the column are entered as text, this should be easily solvable using `=LEFT()`: if the string in the cell is "$100,000", you could use `=LEFT([Cell], 1)` with an `=IF()` condition to check for the currency. If the values are entered as numbers, but formatted as `Currency`, you might want to create a user-defined function in VBA that checks what the cell's `NumberFormat` is, and returns a currency value depending on the input.

**EDIT:** A sketch of a VBA solution might look something like this:

```
Function CurrencyFormat(rng As Range) As String
    If InStr(1, rng.NumberFormat, "€") Then
        CurrencyFormat = "EUR"
    ElseIf InStr(1, rng.NumberFormat, "£") Then
        CurrencyFormat = "GBP"
    ElseIf InStr(1, rng.NumberFormat, "¥") Then
        CurrencyFormat = "JPY"
    Else
        CurrencyFormat = "USD"
    End If
End Function
```

You'd need to extend it to accomodate the currencies that appear in your dataset. You can use the formula's output as a key to search for the relevant FX rate in a separate table (alternatively, if you'll only ever use one FX rate in the spreadsheet, you can change the formula output so that it already returns the spot rate).

Comment: Ah, no they are numbers formatted as currency, treating them as text would be really silly because of the purpose of spreadsheets, to manipulate numbers

Comment: In that case, you'll need to check for the currency based on the range's `NumberFormat`, and return exchange-rate values (or keys to an FX rate table where these can be looked up) based on that.